# How do I verify that my Java code actually sent a POST request?

Tags: java, http, networking, http-post

In my java code, I need to send  a POST request to a server that is run by someone else in order to login on their server. However, my attempt to log in is not working.

I would like to be able to pinpoit which part of my code is producing this error. Is there a way I can check to see if the error lies in the POST request not being sent, making the connection a GET request?

Comment: check the responseCode?

Comment: The problem is, the response from the server is identical to having not sent any data and just used a GET request to retrieve the page, so I'm not sure if it really did send the data I wanted it to send, and I've also heard about people having problems with the data not being sent.

Comment: Temporarily make it use your own server instead. Then watch the server logs. Or if it's not HTTPS you could use Wireshark. (This includes if you use your own non-HTTPS server deliberately for testing)

Answer (score 1):

You can see your request in developer toolbar that is available in browser. If that is not an option for you then you can use tools like Charles Debugger or Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `HttpClient` library to send HTTP POST requests then I would suggest modify your log4j.properties file as follows

```
#Logger configuration for Apache Commons HTTP Client
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%c] %m%n
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=debug, stdout
```

This would print the complete request (Headers, Body, URL & params) & response (Headers, Body) that is going on the wire.

Hope that helps